# Phonegab/Cordova - Launch app on GCM notification like whatsup call

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I use the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3960) to send GCM notification on a mobile device but I'can't find anything how to start an activity when a notification is triggered.

This plugin do the follow:

- if the activity is started and is in forderground then the notification message will be display directy into the activity (this is OK)
- if the activitiy is started and is in background a notification will be displayed and only by clicking on the notification the activity will take into forderground and show the message (should do without click).
- if activity is not starting, nothing is happend

What I want is that the activity should be run in forderground when notification is triggerd, even if the lock screen is active.

Is this scenario even possible with phonegab?